# Select 2nd From Last Entry In MySQL

Tags: mysql

**Problem**: Need 2nd from last entry from each distinct ticket within a specified time period

**Example Data**:

```
ticketTB
ticket createdate          status
111    2015-08-13 04:05:12 good
111    2015-08-13 04:04:12 bad
111    2015-08-13 04:03:12 good
115    2015-08-13 03:05:12 good
115    2015-08-13 03:04:12 bad
115    2015-08-13 03:03:12 good
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT ticket, status, createdate FROM ticketTB GROUP BY ticket ORDER BY createdate DESC LIMIT 1,1;
```

This query pulls:

```
ticket createdate          status
111    2015-08-13 04:04:12 bad
```

However, add in many other tickets it will only pull the 2nd from last of all of those I need it to evaluate every distinct ticket.

I want my query to return:

```
ticket createdate          status
111    2015-08-13 04:04:12 bad
115    2015-08-13 03:04:12 bad
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ticketTB;

CREATE TABLE ticketTB
(ticket INT NOT NULL
,createdate DATETIME NOT NULL
,status VARCHAR(12)
,PRIMARY KEY(ticket,createdate)
);

INSERT INTO ticketTB VALUES
(111    ,'2015-08-13 04:05:12','good'),
(111    ,'2015-08-13 04:04:12','bad'),
(111    ,'2015-08-13 04:03:12','good'),
(111    ,'2015-08-13 04:02:12','good'),
(115    ,'2015-08-13 03:05:12','good'),
(115    ,'2015-08-13 03:04:12','bad'),
(115    ,'2015-08-13 03:03:12','good'),
(115    ,'2015-08-13 03:02:12','good');

SELECT * FROM ticketTB;
+--------+---------------------+--------+
| ticket | createdate          | status |
+--------+---------------------+--------+
|    111 | 2015-08-13 04:02:12 | good   |
|    111 | 2015-08-13 04:03:12 | good   |
|    111 | 2015-08-13 04:04:12 | bad    |
|    111 | 2015-08-13 04:05:12 | good   |
|    115 | 2015-08-13 03:02:12 | good   |
|    115 | 2015-08-13 03:03:12 | good   |
|    115 | 2015-08-13 03:04:12 | bad    |
|    115 | 2015-08-13 03:05:12 | good   |
+--------+---------------------+--------+

SELECT x.* 
  FROM ticketTB x 
  JOIN ticketTB y 
    ON y.ticket = x.ticket 
   AND y.createdate >= x.createdate 
 GROUP 
    BY ticket
     , createdate 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
+--------+---------------------+--------+
| ticket | createdate          | status |
+--------+---------------------+--------+
|    111 | 2015-08-13 04:04:12 | bad    |
|    115 | 2015-08-13 03:04:12 | bad    |
+--------+---------------------+--------+
```

Something like the following method will generally be faster, especially so on larger data sets...

```
SELECT ticket
     , createdate
     , status 
  FROM
     ( SELECT *
            , CASE WHEN @prev = ticket THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank
            , @prev := ticket prev 
         FROM ticketTB
            , (SELECT @prev:='',@i:=1) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY ticket
            , createdate DESC
     ) x 
 WHERE rank = 2;
+--------+---------------------+--------+
| ticket | createdate          | status |
+--------+---------------------+--------+
|    111 | 2015-08-13 04:04:12 | bad    |
|    115 | 2015-08-13 03:04:12 | bad    |
+--------+---------------------+--------+
```

Comment: taking a long time to run as my actual table is much larger.

Comment: I modified it a little JOIN (SELECT * FROM ticket_text) ttt ON ttt.ticket_num = tt.ticket_num AND ttt.create_date >= tt.create_date

Comment: There is no ticket_text table so I don't know why you would do that - and this wouldn't aid performance

Comment: My apologies.... JOIN (SELECT * FROM ticketTB) y ON y.ticket = x.ticket AND y.createdate >= x.createdate

My problem is much more complex then what I've given. I'm trying to get to a root solution to my over all problem and my table and column names are different.

Comment: This worked though! just takes a long time to run on a large table which is fine.

Comment: the second solution is really awesome and works quickly.  Thank you for your help and solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 2,1
```

Comment: I feel like my question may not be organized to be understandable, but they do not have a rating.  The only way to distinguish between a series (that is one that came before the other) is by the createdate.  I want the 2nd from last for each distinct ticket in my table.

Comment: I've edited my post to add another column, this shows why I might need the 2nd from last.  Consider there are multiple tickets with multiple updates for each.  I need that 2nd from last update for each one.